# Как сделать в SVG незамкнутый путь с двух сторон?

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, css-animation

Возник такой вопрос, возможно ли в векторе создать фигуру из двух незамкнутых путей? Приведу пример

```html
 <svg version="1.1" id="ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 400;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;}
 .st1{fill:#FBE731;stroke:#B1A333;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g id="RightRing">
 <path class="st0" d="M302.3,210.8c36.3,0,65.8-5.7,65.8-12.8c0-7.1-29.4-12.8-65.8-12.8c-0.4,0-0.9,0-1.3,0v25.6
  C301.4,210.8,301.9,210.8,302.3,210.8z"/>
 <path id="rightSide" class="st1" d="M303,226.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c49.3,0,89.2-11.9,89.2-26.7c0-14.8-40-26.7-89.5-26.7v12.2
  c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c36.3,0,66.9,5.7,66.9,12.8c0,7.1-29.5,12.8-65.8,12.8c-0.4,0-0.7,0-1.1,0c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0"/>
</g>
<g id="LeftRing">
 <path class="st0" d="M304.2,210.8c-36.3,0-65.8-5.7-65.8-12.8c0-7.1,29.4-12.8,65.8-12.8c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0v25.6
  C305.1,210.8,304.6,210.8,304.2,210.8z"/>
 <path id="rightSide_1_" class="st1" d="M303.5,226.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-49.3,0-89.2-11.9-89.2-26.7c0-14.8,40-26.7,89.5-26.7
  v12.2c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-36.3,0-66.9,5.7-66.9,12.8c0,7.1,29.5,12.8,65.8,12.8c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Здесь два полу-кольца. Но у меня не получается убрать обводку `stroke` с верхних части данной фигуры. Может кто-то посоветовать, как это реализовать. В дальнейшем эти два полукольца планируется анимировать. Должна происходить анимация постепенного закрашивания с верхней части в нижнюю.

Comment: Убрать вертикальную черточку вверху или, если провести воображаемую горизонтальную ось по центру эллипса, то убрать всю обводку, что выше её?

Comment: Там на самом деле две черточки, проста одна поверх другой. Но вообщем, да. Нужно их убрать. Оно должно смотреться как замкнутое кольцо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно пойти по другому пути. Нарисовать один патч вместо четырех. С одним патчем и анимировать при этом легче будет. Но надо точно узнать длину этого патча, чтобы потом использовать её в анимации посредством свойства `stroke-dasharray` Для определения длины пути нужно подставить своё значение  строки `path`, начинающейся с `d="m322....58z"`

```html
<body>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="TotalLength"
            onclick="TotalLength()"/>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400" 
 style="border:1px dotted red;">
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="green" stroke-width ="10" 
         d="m322 255a188 58 0 0 1-188-58 188 58 0 0 1 188-58 188 58 0 0 1 188 58 188 58 0 0 1-188 58z" />
    </svg>


<script>
 function TotalLength(){
  var path = document.querySelector('#check');
   var len = path.getTotalLength();
    console.log('Длина равна - ' +len);
};
</script>
</body>
```

После нажатия на кнопку `TotalLenght` из модального окна берем длину нашего патча и подставляем в `stroke-dasharray`.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 400;" >
    <path id="shape" fill="none" stroke-width="15" stroke="gold" d="m322 255a188 58 0 0 1-188-58 188 58 0 0 1 188-58 188 58 0 0 1 188 58 188 58 0 0 1-188 58z" />
  <animate
        xlink:href="#shape" 
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray" 
        from="0 413.5 0 413.5" to="0 0 827 0" 
        begin="0s"
        dur="3.3s" 
        repeatCount="3"
    />
</svg>
```

Обратите внимание, что вместо 2-х атрибутов `stroke-dasharray` использовано четыре. Для того, чтобы анимация шла из середины пути в разные стороны нужно разделить полную длину на пополам 827/2 = `413.5`  Для окончания анимации подставляется полная длина пути `827` То есть эффект анимации достигается за счет увеличения длины штриха с `0` до полной длины и соответственно идет одновременное уменьшение пробела между штрихами от максимума до нуля.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно. Используй `m` для прохождения этой линии, чтобы она не рисовалась.
`v` не подходит, т. к. рисует линию.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 600 400;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;}
 .st1{fill:#FBE731;stroke:#B1A333;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g id="RightRing">
 <path class="st0" d="M302.3,210.8c36.3,0,65.8-5.7,65.8-12.8c0-7.1-29.4-12.8-65.8-12.8c-0.4,0-0.9,0-1.3,0m0,25.6
  C301.4,210.8,301.9,210.8,302.3,210.8z"/>
 <path id="rightSide" class="st1" d="M303,226.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c49.3,0,89.2-11.9,89.2-26.7c0-14.8-40-26.7-89.5-26.7m0,12.2
  c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c36.3,0,66.9,5.7,66.9,12.8c0,7.1-29.5,12.8-65.8,12.8c-0.4,0-0.7,0-1.1,0c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0"/>
</g>
<g id="LeftRing">
 <path class="st0" d="M304.2,210.8c-36.3,0-65.8-5.7-65.8-12.8c0-7.1,29.4-12.8,65.8-12.8c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0m0,25.6
  C305.1,210.8,304.6,210.8,304.2,210.8z"/>
 <path id="rightSide_1_" class="st1" d="M303.5,226.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-49.3,0-89.2-11.9-89.2-26.7c0-14.8,40-26.7,89.5-26.7
  m0,12.2c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-36.3,0-66.9,5.7-66.9,12.8c0,7.1,29.5,12.8,65.8,12.8c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0"/>
</g>
</svg>
```