# Анимировать по очереди SVG Path

Tags: javascript, svg

Как анимировать сначала первый тег path, а затем другой?

```js
function ready() {

  var path;
  var elem = document.getElementById("elem");
  var line = elem.getElementsByTagName("path");

  for (var i = 0; line.length > i; i++) {

    line[i].style.strokeDashoffset = path;
    line[i].style.strokeDasharray = path;
    path = line[i].getTotalLength();

    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
      var int = setInterval(draw, 50);

      function draw() {
        if (path <= 0) {
          clearInterval(int);
        } else {
          path += 20 * (-1);
          line[i].style.strokeDashoffset = path;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>

<svg version="1.1" id="elem" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:#2A2874;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M58.8,49.9c-8.5,24.3-8.9,50.7-15.4,75.7 c-3.7,13.9-10.4,28.6-23.6,34.2c-4.2-9.4-0.4-20.3,3.5-29.8c8.8-21.4,18.4-42.8,32.1-61.5c6.2-8.5,14.7-17.1,25.3-16.8 c1,0,2,0.1,2.8,0.6c1.5,0.9,2,2.7,2.3,4.4c1.5,9.1-1.1,18.5-5.6,26.6c-4.5,8-10.9,14.9-17.4,21.4c4.1,0.8,8.3,0.6,12.4,1.2 s8.4,2.3,10.5,5.8c3.4,5.6,0.1,12.8-3.5,18.2c-5.8,8.7-14,17.7-24.5,17.2c12.4-16.9,33.9-23.7,51.5-35.1c13.5-8.8,25-20.8,33.3-34.6 c3.6-6.1,6.8-13.1,5.6-20.1c-0.5-3.3-2.2-6.6-5.2-8c-4,14.9-2,30.8-4.5,46c-2.4,14.6-8.9,28.1-15.3,41.4c-1.7,3.5-3.4,7.1-6.3,9.7 c-2.9,2.6-7.1,4.1-10.7,2.5c-1.9-0.8-3.5-2.7-3.4-4.7c0.2-2.5,3-4.2,5.5-3.9s4.6,1.8,6.4,3.6c4.3,4.3,7.5,10,12.8,12.9 c4.8,2.6,10.8,2.6,15.9,0.8c5.2-1.8,9.7-5.2,13.7-8.9c14-13.1,23-31.3,25-50.4c1.9-19.1-3.3-38.7-14.4-54.4 c-4.8-6.7-10.5-12.6-16.4-18.4c-3.5-3.5-7.1-7-11.5-9.2c-9.7-4.9-21.3-3-31.8-0.4c-19.3,4.8-38.2,11.3-56.3,19.6 c-7.9,3.6-16.1,7.9-21,15.1c-3.6,5.2-5.1,11.6-6.1,17.8c-1.3,8.1-1.8,16.9,2.2,24.1c3.3,5.9,9.1,9.8,15,13.2 c27.1,15.8,58.3,24.8,89.7,25.8c5,0.2,10.1,0.1,14.9-1.5c3.6-1.2,6.9-3.3,10.1-5.4c12.3-7.9,24.5-15.8,36.8-23.6 c3.2-2.1,6.9-5.5,5.4-9"/>
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:#195A2D;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M14.8,180.6c2.4-0.7,4.3-2.6,6.4-3.9 c6.2-3.7,14.3-1.9,21,0.8s13.5,6.3,20.8,5.9c8.4-0.5,15.8-6.5,24.2-6.8c11.5-0.5,21.7,9.4,33.2,8.7c8.9-0.6,17.1-7.5,25.9-5.9 c4.3,0.8,8.1,3.6,12.4,4.5c5.9,1.3,11.9-1.2,17.4-3.6c1.9-0.8,4.1-2.6,3.1-4.4"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне именно нужно с js анимировать, что если там 2 или больше тега Path, для каждого писать долго, нужно как javascript'м сделать, чтобы по порядку анимировалось

Comment: с одним тегом Path я ниже написал рабочий код

Comment: рабочий код тот что внизу, там где тег Path один, не работает тот что с двумя тегами Path - и я не знаю почему, поэтому и задал здесь вопрос этот

Answer (score 10):

Pure SVG

```html
<svg  version="1.1" id="elem" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">


  <path style="fill:none;stroke:#2A2874;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="1243"  stroke-dashoffset="1243" d="M 58.8,49.9 C 50.3,74.2 49.9,100.6 43.4,125.6 39.7,139.5 33,154.2 19.8,159.8 15.6,150.4 19.4,139.5 23.3,130 32.1,108.6 41.7,87.2 55.4,68.5 61.6,60 70.1,51.4 80.7,51.7 c 1,0 2,0.1 2.8,0.6 1.5,0.9 2,2.7 2.3,4.4 1.5,9.1 -1.1,18.5 -5.6,26.6 -4.5,8 -10.9,14.9 -17.4,21.4 4.1,0.8 8.3,0.6 12.4,1.2 4.1,0.6 8.4,2.3 10.5,5.8 3.4,5.6 0.1,12.8 -3.5,18.2 -5.8,8.7 -26.208203,32.84354 -24.5,17.2 1.708203,-15.64354 33.9,-23.7 51.5,-35.1 13.5,-8.8 25,-20.8 33.3,-34.6 3.6,-6.1 6.8,-13.1 5.6,-20.1 -0.5,-3.3 -2.81735,-10.298475 -5.2,-8 -9.67278,9.331069 -2,30.8 -4.5,46 -2.4,14.6 -8.9,28.1 -15.3,41.4 -1.7,3.5 -3.4,7.1 -6.3,9.7 -2.9,2.6 -7.1,4.1 -10.7,2.5 -1.9,-0.8 -3.5,-2.7 -3.4,-4.7 0.2,-2.5 3,-4.2 5.5,-3.9 2.5,0.3 4.6,1.8 6.4,3.6 4.3,4.3 7.5,10 12.8,12.9 4.8,2.6 10.8,2.6 15.9,0.8 5.2,-1.8 9.7,-5.2 13.7,-8.9 14,-13.1 23,-31.3 25,-50.4 1.9,-19.1 -3.3,-38.7 -14.4,-54.4 -4.8,-6.7 -10.5,-12.6 -16.4,-18.4 -3.5,-3.5 -7.1,-7 -11.5,-9.2 -9.7,-4.9 -21.3,-3 -31.8,-0.4 -19.3,4.8 -38.2,11.3 -56.3,19.6 -7.9,3.6 -16.1,7.9 -21,15.1 -3.6,5.2 -5.1,11.6 -6.1,17.8 -1.3,8.1 -1.8,16.9 2.2,24.1 3.3,5.9 9.1,9.8 15,13.2 27.1,15.8 58.3,24.8 89.7,25.8 5,0.2 10.1,0.1 14.9,-1.5 3.6,-1.2 6.9,-3.3 10.1,-5.4 12.3,-7.9 24.5,-15.8 36.8,-23.6 3.2,-2.1 6.9,-5.5 5.4,-9">
  <animate id="an1"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="0;an2.end+1s"
    values="1243; 0"
    dur="8s"
    fill="freeze"
    calcMode="linear"
    restart="whenNotActive" />     
</path>   

     <path style="fill:none;stroke:#195A2D;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="175"  stroke-dashoffset="175" d="M14.8,180.6c2.4-0.7,4.3-2.6,6.4-3.9
        c6.2-3.7,14.3-1.9,21,0.8s13.5,6.3,20.8,5.9c8.4-0.5,15.8-6.5,24.2-6.8c11.5-0.5,21.7,9.4,33.2,8.7c8.9-0.6,17.1-7.5,25.9-5.9
        c4.3,0.8,8.1,3.6,12.4,4.5c5.9,1.3,11.9-1.2,17.4-3.6c1.9-0.8,4.1-2.6,3.1-4.4">
    <animate id="an2"
       attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
       begin="an1.end"
       values="175; 0"
       dur="2s"
       calcMode="linear"
       restart="whenNotActive" />     
   </path>
    </svg>
```

Добавил viewport  `width="200"` `height="200"`, так как без этого подпись была на весь экран. Исправил `path`, так как в статике не видно было разрыва линии, но при анимации на месте разрыва была остановка.
добавил строки, реализующие анимацию c `id="an1"`и  `id="an2"` соответственно  Начало первой анимации команда `begin="0"` Второй анимации - `begin="an1.end"`, то есть видно, что она запускается после окончания первой анимации.  Команда - `restart="whenNotActive"` служит для запрета повторной анимации, пока не закончилась текущая анимация.

**Принцип действия**

Линия скрывается установкой `stroke-dashoffset` равной длине пути. А затем stroke-dashoffset уменьшается до нуля, тем самым реализуя эффект рисования линии. [Подробнее здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1253#more-1253).
Длину линии, которую будем подставлять, можно вычислить по этому [способу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626827/svg-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD/627027#627027). 
Это важно, так как наугад подставлять длину в `stroke-dashoffset` не стоит.
Если её длина будет намного больше реальной длины патча, то будет задержка между анимациями, если меньше, то часть линии будет всегда видна.

Comment: Спустя несколько секунд вижу анимацию волны и всё, так и задумано?

Answer (score 3):

**Анимация с помощью JS**

```html
 <svg  version="1.1" id="elem" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" onload="init(evt)" >

<script><![CDATA[
function init(evt)
{svgdoc=evt.target.ownerDocument
varia=svgdoc.getElementById('letter');
long=Math.round(varia.getTotalLength());
varia.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',long.toString()+","+long.toString());
varia.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset',long.toString());
obj=svgdoc.getElementById('an1');
obj.setAttribute('from',long.toString());
varia=svgdoc.getElementById('wave');
long=varia.getTotalLength();
varia.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',long.toString()+","+long.toString());
varia.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset',long.toString());
obj=svgdoc.getElementById('an2');
obj.setAttribute('from',long.toString());
}
]]></script>
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="dodgerblue" /> 
  <path id="letter" style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="0,0" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M 58.8,49.9 C 50.3,74.2 49.9,100.6 43.4,125.6 39.7,139.5 33,154.2 19.8,159.8 15.6,150.4 19.4,139.5 23.3,130 32.1,108.6 41.7,87.2 55.4,68.5 61.6,60 70.1,51.4 80.7,51.7 c 1,0 2,0.1 2.8,0.6 1.5,0.9 2,2.7 2.3,4.4 1.5,9.1 -1.1,18.5 -5.6,26.6 -4.5,8 -10.9,14.9 -17.4,21.4 4.1,0.8 8.3,0.6 12.4,1.2 4.1,0.6 8.4,2.3 10.5,5.8 3.4,5.6 0.1,12.8 -3.5,18.2 -5.8,8.7 -14,17.7 -24.5,17.2 12.4,-16.9 33.9,-23.7 51.5,-35.1 13.5,-8.8 25,-20.8 33.3,-34.6 3.6,-6.1 6.8,-13.1 5.6,-20.1 -9.3021,-22.522978 -8.72235,31.643578 -9.7,38 -2.4,14.6 -8.9,28.1 -15.3,41.4 -1.7,3.5 -3.4,7.1 -6.3,9.7 -21.996339,32.8476 -24.324622,-7.01388 -8.6,-6.1 2.5,0.3 4.6,1.8 6.4,3.6 4.3,4.3 7.5,10 12.8,12.9 4.8,2.6 10.8,2.6 15.9,0.8 5.2,-1.8 9.7,-5.2 13.7,-8.9 14,-13.1 23,-31.3 25,-50.4 1.9,-19.1 -3.3,-38.7 -14.4,-54.4 -36.0255,-46.9750306 -113.66513,-25.470006 -137,6.7 -3.6,5.2 -5.1,11.6 -6.1,17.8 -1.3,8.1 -1.8,16.9 2.2,24.1 3.3,5.9 9.1,9.8 15,13.2 28.505405,25.14337 156.17688,40.97193 155.59281,-12.066013">
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced"/> 
  </path>
      <path id="wave" style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0,0" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="M14.8,180.6c2.4-0.7,4.3-2.6,6.4-3.9
            c6.2-3.7,14.3-1.9,21,0.8s13.5,6.3,20.8,5.9c8.4-0.5,15.8-6.5,24.2-6.8c11.5-0.5,21.7,9.4,33.2,8.7c8.9-0.6,17.1-7.5,25.9-5.9
            c4.3,0.8,8.1,3.6,12.4,4.5c5.9,1.3,11.9-1.2,17.4-3.6c1.9-0.8,4.1-2.6,3.1-4.4">
   <animate id="an2" begin="an1.end" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="175" to="0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced"/> 
   </path>
    
      
  </svg>
```

Принцип действия тот же, как и в варианте с SVG. 
Измеряется длина пути с помощью команды `getTotalLength()` и подставляется в команду `stroke-dashoffset`. Анимация достигается при плавном уменьшении значения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` от максимума - длины пути - до нулевого значения, обеспечивая тем самым рисование линии от нуля до конца.
Когда закончится первая анимация id="an1" рисование букв, начинается вторая анимация по команде `begin="an1.end"`

Comment: на последнем проэкте у меня было 20 иконок svg с большим количеством тегов, и для каждого писать id или <animate> и тд - это унылое дело

Answer (score 2):

С одним тегом работает скрипт
html:

```js
  function ready() {

    var path;
    var line = document.getElementById("elem");
        path = line.getTotalLength();
        line.style.strokeDashoffset = path;
        line.style.strokeDasharray = path;

    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
            var int = setInterval(draw, 50);

            function draw() {
                if (path <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(int);
                } else {
                    path += 20 * (-1);
                    line.style.strokeDashoffset = path;
                }
            }
        }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
<svg version="1.1" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
            <path id="elem" style="fill:none;stroke:#2A2874;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M58.8,49.9c-8.5,24.3-8.9,50.7-15.4,75.7
            c-3.7,13.9-10.4,28.6-23.6,34.2c-4.2-9.4-0.4-20.3,3.5-29.8c8.8-21.4,18.4-42.8,32.1-61.5c6.2-8.5,14.7-17.1,25.3-16.8
            c1,0,2,0.1,2.8,0.6c1.5,0.9,2,2.7,2.3,4.4c1.5,9.1-1.1,18.5-5.6,26.6c-4.5,8-10.9,14.9-17.4,21.4c4.1,0.8,8.3,0.6,12.4,1.2
            s8.4,2.3,10.5,5.8c3.4,5.6,0.1,12.8-3.5,18.2c-5.8,8.7-14,17.7-24.5,17.2c12.4-16.9,33.9-23.7,51.5-35.1c13.5-8.8,25-20.8,33.3-34.6
            c3.6-6.1,6.8-13.1,5.6-20.1c-0.5-3.3-2.2-6.6-5.2-8c-4,14.9-2,30.8-4.5,46c-2.4,14.6-8.9,28.1-15.3,41.4c-1.7,3.5-3.4,7.1-6.3,9.7
            c-2.9,2.6-7.1,4.1-10.7,2.5c-1.9-0.8-3.5-2.7-3.4-4.7c0.2-2.5,3-4.2,5.5-3.9s4.6,1.8,6.4,3.6c4.3,4.3,7.5,10,12.8,12.9
            c4.8,2.6,10.8,2.6,15.9,0.8c5.2-1.8,9.7-5.2,13.7-8.9c14-13.1,23-31.3,25-50.4c1.9-19.1-3.3-38.7-14.4-54.4
            c-4.8-6.7-10.5-12.6-16.4-18.4c-3.5-3.5-7.1-7-11.5-9.2c-9.7-4.9-21.3-3-31.8-0.4c-19.3,4.8-38.2,11.3-56.3,19.6
            c-7.9,3.6-16.1,7.9-21,15.1c-3.6,5.2-5.1,11.6-6.1,17.8c-1.3,8.1-1.8,16.9,2.2,24.1c3.3,5.9,9.1,9.8,15,13.2
            c27.1,15.8,58.3,24.8,89.7,25.8c5,0.2,10.1,0.1,14.9-1.5c3.6-1.2,6.9-3.3,10.1-5.4c12.3-7.9,24.5-15.8,36.8-23.6
            c3.2-2.1,6.9-5.5,5.4-9"/>
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Доработал патч, дуги стали более ровные, буквы немного подправил, добавил анимацию градиентов.

```html
 <svg  version="1.1" id="elem" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" >
        <animate 
          attributeName="offset" 
          from="0%"
          to="100%"
          begin="0s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad1)" /> 
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="1243"  stroke-dashoffset="1243" d="M 58.8,49.9 C 50.3,74.2 49.9,100.6 43.4,125.6 39.7,139.5 33,154.2 19.8,159.8 15.6,150.4 19.4,139.5 23.3,130 32.1,108.6 41.7,87.2 55.4,68.5 61.6,60 70.1,51.4 80.7,51.7 c 1,0 2,0.1 2.8,0.6 1.5,0.9 2,2.7 2.3,4.4 1.5,9.1 -1.1,18.5 -5.6,26.6 -4.5,8 -10.9,14.9 -17.4,21.4 4.1,0.8 8.3,0.6 12.4,1.2 4.1,0.6 8.4,2.3 10.5,5.8 3.4,5.6 0.1,12.8 -3.5,18.2 -5.8,8.7 -14,17.7 -24.5,17.2 12.4,-16.9 33.9,-23.7 51.5,-35.1 13.5,-8.8 25,-20.8 33.3,-34.6 3.6,-6.1 6.8,-13.1 5.6,-20.1 -9.3021,-22.522978 -8.72235,31.643578 -9.7,38 -2.4,14.6 -8.9,28.1 -15.3,41.4 -1.7,3.5 -3.4,7.1 -6.3,9.7 -21.996339,32.8476 -24.324622,-7.01388 -8.6,-6.1 2.5,0.3 4.6,1.8 6.4,3.6 4.3,4.3 7.5,10 12.8,12.9 4.8,2.6 10.8,2.6 15.9,0.8 5.2,-1.8 9.7,-5.2 13.7,-8.9 14,-13.1 23,-31.3 25,-50.4 1.9,-19.1 -3.3,-38.7 -14.4,-54.4 -36.0255,-46.9750306 -113.66513,-25.470006 -137,6.7 -3.6,5.2 -5.1,11.6 -6.1,17.8 -1.3,8.1 -1.8,16.9 2.2,24.1 3.3,5.9 9.1,9.8 15,13.2 28.505405,25.14337 156.17688,40.97193 155.59281,-12.066013">
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0;an2.end" 
         values="1243; 0" dur="8s"  fill="freeze" calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive" />     
</path>   

     <path style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-miterlimit:10;" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="175"  stroke-dashoffset="175" d="M14.8,180.6c2.4-0.7,4.3-2.6,6.4-3.9
            c6.2-3.7,14.3-1.9,21,0.8s13.5,6.3,20.8,5.9c8.4-0.5,15.8-6.5,24.2-6.8c11.5-0.5,21.7,9.4,33.2,8.7c8.9-0.6,17.1-7.5,25.9-5.9
            c4.3,0.8,8.1,3.6,12.4,4.5c5.9,1.3,11.9-1.2,17.4-3.6c1.9-0.8,4.1-2.6,3.1-4.4">
    <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an1.end" 
         values="175; 0" dur="4s"    calcMode="linear" restart="whenNotActive" />     
   </path> 
      
  </svg>
```

Анимация градиентов здесь работает только в FF.  Хром, опера, яндекс, IE -всё мимо.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8shxnbo/2/)